# How Betelgeuse captured Subaru's body like in the ending of episode 23?

Tags: re-zero

How Betelgeuse captured Subaru's body?

Spoiler alert if you didn't watch episode 25:

> In the ending of episode 23, he captured Subaru's body which some would think was possible because Subaru has touched the book. But he didn't touch it in episode 25 and still Betelgeuse was able to capture him.

How? Why?

Comment: Wild guess 1 - it's going to be explained in a later episode, just be patient; wild guess 2 - they already told you how it happens a few episodes ago, take a look back.

Comment: Nice catch by ConMan! I think that's it, and it's gonna be explained in detail in the next episode.

Comment: Definitely going to be explained and clarified in next episode probably, but I'm pretty sure Betelgeuse goes from body to body when he has to make a new finger.
Conman could be please say what episode.

Comment: @ConMan well now, I may not be an avid fan, but i am pretty sure i missed the reason completely, and since the season is over, there obviously will not be a direct explanation, at least not for a long time. Can i get a hint?

Comment: Well, having watched the season finale, it looks like my suspicions were both wrong - I assumed that either (a) it related to him holding onto the book (as some characters explicitly warned that having a copy of the book was dangerous), or (b) it related to his being "touched" by the witch, and while either is still possible it was never confirmed one way or another, although events of the finale definitely strengthen the "because he's touched by the witch" possibility.

Comment: @ConMan I also assumed that it was related to holding the book, but definitely not to being touched by the witch. But now even holding the book doesn't make sense since in the last episode Subaru didn't touch the book when Betelgeuse jumped into his body.

Comment: Ok guys, I've changed the question to be matched with our current state :)

Answer (score 1):

In episode 23 at 11:40.

> When Julius was having a conversation with Subaru, he said that Subaru might have an affinity for spirits. Since Petelgeuse was a spirit himself, he could possess the fingers' body which had been cast spell on beforehand and even entities having affinity for spirits. According to Julius, Subaru definitely matches the case.